# What do the last four digits of this postal cancellation stamp mean?

Tags: germany, postal-history

[image: German franking mark]

How does one interpret the last digits "10-11"? The ones after the date?

Comment: Today, they would mark the time. It's optional and normally only one number is used for the hour, nobody cares for minutes. Casual browsing did not show any *changes* to this after WW2, so I would expect it has probably been this way for a long time, but then, my casual browsing is hardly an authorative source. That's why this is a comment only.

Comment: According to wikipedia, the hour has been included in these stamps from the 1820s on or so, so it is quite safe to assume this has been stamped between 10 and 11 o'clock. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagesstempel

Comment: Some more relevant  info [here](https://stampboards.com/viewtopic.php?t=47809#:~:text=Your%20second%20cancel%20(%20the%20genuine%20one)%20actually%20doesn%27t%20use%20the%2024%20hour%20system%20.%20the%20time%20is%20shown%20as%2010%2D11%20V%20(%20Forenoon)%20after%2012%20it%20becomes%201%2D2%20N%20Nachmitag%20(%20Afternoon)%20so%20is%20not%20using%20the%2024%20hour%20system%20but%20splits%20the%20day%20into%20two%2012%20hour%20periods%20.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does one interpret the last digits "10-11"? The ones after the date?

It is a time indication: **between** 10 and 11.

Somtimes they would use:

- **V** for AM (0-11)
- **N** for PM (12-23)

Around 1956 the 24 hour notation was mostly used.

These stamps were not only used for the cancellation of stamps, but often used for other documentation purposes

- on the back of the letter, a destination stamp may be found
- entries for postal saving books also used this stamp

Post office officials, as state employees, could certify the content of a letter and would used this stamp on the copies that could then be presented to a court.

> [image]
>
> - Stamp head of a hand stamp (fist stamp, hammer stamp, self-inking stamp), day stamp (Tagesstempel) Lübeck 1, 3-4 PM

> [image]
> Small style stamp used until 1956 (1964 in East Germany)

> [image]
> Larger stamp used between 1956 and 1962 with 24 hour notation

> [image]
> Larger stamp used between 1962 and 1993 with postal code at the bottom (Deutsche Bundespost, West).
>
> - Around 1981 with added 0's (1000 instead of 1)
>
> Here they are being used in a postal saving book

> [image]
> Larger stamp used between 1965 and 1993 with postal code at the top (Deutsche Post, East).

> [image]
>
> Larger stamp used since 1993-07-01 with 5 diget postal code

---

**Sources**:

- [Stempel und Stempelabschläge – Museum für Kommunikation – Sammlungen](https://sammlungen.museumsstiftung.de/stempel-und-stempelabschlaege/)